# Bullet doesnt dissapear when hittign a collision unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo7bq.png)i am making a script where the player can shoot in my unity game. This works but the bullet doesnt go away when hitting a collision. Can anyone help me with this problem?  this is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletDie : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject diePEffect;
    public float dieTime;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Timer());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    private void OncollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        GameObject collisionGameObject = collision.gameObject;
        if (collisionGameObject.name != "Player")
        {
            Die();
         

        }

    }
    IEnumerator Timer()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dieTime);
        Die();
    }

    void Die()
    {
        if (diePEffect != null)
        {
            Instantiate(diePEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have added colision component on the enemy , that might be the problem

Comment: Add a debug.Log on the OnCollisionEnter function to check if the function is executed or not

Comment: Isn't the problem only a typo? You wrote `OncollisionEnter2D` but the name should be `OnCollisionEnter2D` with a upper "C" on "Collision". I'm not sure that this is the problem, but it's worth a try